# Selectively switch on/off multiple types of comments

Tags: comments

I want to have 3 types of comments. *Comments* means it is (special formatted, e.g. colored) text in the resulting PDF file.

I want to switch them on or off selectively. I am not sure which of the comment related packages is related here.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\usepackage{comment}
\includecomment{comment}

\begin{document}
\begin{comment}
comment - only for me
\end{comment}

\begin{comment}
comment - only for advisor A
\end{comment}

\begin{comment}
comment - for advisor A and B
\end{comment}
\end{document}
```

The background to my question: I write a thesis as a student having two advisors.

- There are comments/notes only for my eyes.
- Comments only for advisor A but not for B.
- Comments for A and B.

Depending on who I am showing the current state of my paper I need to switch off one or two types of the comments.

Comment: There are lots of packages which are fitting your needs. E.g. `comment`, `luatodonotes`, `todonotes`, etc. https://www.ctan.org/topic/editorial

Comment: @marcodaniel The question wasn't about selecting a package. It was about how to solve me needs with them.

Comment: For me the question is too broad. I can provide an answer using the package `comment` After this your needs are increasing and so we change to something else -- and so on. Is there a possibility that you want a comment for A and you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three environments: `commentA`, `commentB`, and `commentC`.  They can be selectively turned on and off with `\Aon`, `\Aoff`, `\Bon`, `\Boff`, `\Con`, and `\Coff`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,lipsum,xcolor}
\NewEnviron{commentA}{}
\newcommand\Aon{\RenewEnviron{commentA}{\color{red}\BODY}}
\newcommand\Aoff{\RenewEnviron{commentA}{}}
\NewEnviron{commentB}{}
\newcommand\Bon{\RenewEnviron{commentB}{\color{blue}\BODY}}
\newcommand\Boff{\RenewEnviron{commentB}{}}
\NewEnviron{commentC}{}
\newcommand\Con{\RenewEnviron{commentC}{\color{cyan}\BODY}}
\newcommand\Coff{\RenewEnviron{commentC}{}}
\begin{document}
\Aon
\Bon
\Con
\lipsum[1]
\begin{commentA}
\lipsum[2]
\end{commentA}
\begin{commentB}
\lipsum[2]
\end{commentB}
\begin{commentC}
\lipsum[2]
\end{commentC}

\Aoff
\lipsum[1]
\begin{commentA}
\lipsum[2]
\end{commentA}
\begin{commentB}
\lipsum[2]
\end{commentB}
\begin{commentC}
\lipsum[2]
\end{commentC}

\Boff
\lipsum[1]
\begin{commentA}
\lipsum[2]
\end{commentA}
\begin{commentB}
\lipsum[2]
\end{commentB}
\begin{commentC}
\lipsum[2]
\end{commentC}

\Coff
\lipsum[1]
\begin{commentA}
\lipsum[2]
\end{commentA}
\begin{commentB}
\lipsum[2]
\end{commentB}
\begin{commentC}
\lipsum[2]
\end{commentC}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be that there is no hyphenation in that comment blocks?

Comment: @buhtz No, that is not the case.  If I put `\lipsum[1]` in the comment block, it hyphenates just fine.

Comment: What is if you use `scrartcl` as documentclass?

Comment: @buhtz When I take my MWE and replace `article` with `scrartcl`, everything compiles just fine.